# Is there a way to access a special folder path using a special folder name as a string using C#

Tags: c#, reflection, special-folders

I have a text value from an App.Config file I read which identifies a special folder to use such as "LocalApplicationData". I would like to use this text value to access an Environment.SpecialFolder value. I have tried the below code statement but it does not work. Can someone please point out what is wrong or is there another way I should try?

```
object value = typeof(Environment.SpecialFolder).GetProperty("LocalApplicationData").GetValue(null);
```

Normally a special folder path is returned with a statement like the following:

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData)
```

This is fine if I know in advance which special folder to specify. But in this problem case, the special folder name can be several values and is read from a app.config file. This is for a WinForms application not a web application.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It isn't a property.

Comment: See [Application Settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/application-settings-for-windows-forms). Hth.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
var s = // read value from config.  Store in string
SpecialFolder sf;
if( Enum.TryParse( s, true, out sf))
{
    // success, now let's get the actual path
    var actualPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(sf)
}
```

Comment: Of course, the result still needs to be passed to `Environment.GetFolderPath`